# How to align the image in image button

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to place my image with in the allocated image button view. but it doesn't fixed with in that space and it looks odd ! ! is it possible to align the image with in allocated space for image button or i have to crop and set up ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Image in the ImageButton tag to be aligned to the left.

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" 
    android:src="@drawable/sample" >
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply ! i ll try this and let u know the outcome!

Comment: android:scaleType="fitStart" done the magic ! ! thanks @Ganesh Rengarajan :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Button. In button you have four option to put image and padding to image

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="Button" />
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for ur reply ! i ll try this and let u know the outcome!

Answer (score 4):

you can align image in imagebutton using **scaleType** attribute.

if you want to set in left then just try below:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:layoutGravity=""
android:gravity=""
```